# How to make a get_prefix in discord.py mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, discord.py

I am trying to make a custom prefix and im not sure how to get my prefix from my database in mongodb

if anyone can help, ty!

Comment: Hey there callimarie! Have you tried anything? Stackoverflow isn't _supposed_ to be a site where people hand you code on a silver platter, but instead a site that helps you improve what you already have. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried, as well as any traceback that you would've received. Do also visit [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further details. Happy coding!

Comment: @Bagle yes, i have tried on my own, didn't exactly get any good results or at least ones that broke the bot, it is why i came here. i did get something working though.

Comment: You could edit your question to include the code, still. It's better than nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
predb = cluster["discord"]["prefix"]


async def get_prefix(client, message):
    stats = await predb.find_one({"guild": message.guild.id})
    # server_prefix = stats["prefix"]
    if stats is None:
        updated = {"guild": message.guild.id, "prefix": "?"} 
        await predb.insert_one(updated)
        extras = "?"
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(extras)(client, message)
    else:
        extras = stats["prefix"]
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(extras)(client, message)
```

use this in getting prefix

Comment: 44|skye    |   File "/root/skye/main.py", line 27, in get_prefix
44|skye    |     stats = await predb.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id})
44|skye    | TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression

got this error